# Python - How to have same maximum on multiple histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have two distribution with different spread, say

```
a=N.random.normal(0,0.5,500)      
b=N.random.normal(1,3.,500)
```

I want to make an histogram of them where the maximum is at the same level.

If I make normalised histograms with density=True parameter, it will make that area of both histograms will be 1, bit it wont change the fact that maximums are different.

```
P.hist(a, histtype='step', lw=2, cumulative=True)
P.hist(b, histtype='step', color='r', lw=2, density=True)
```

[image: normalized histo]

What I want is to make a histogram where it is "normalized" with the maximum values. I mean when maximum of blue and red histogram would be the same, so it could be easy to compare them. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I would do that really, but if you want to I think the best way is to add two axes (also so that you can see how tall they really are). For example, see here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.hist(a, histtype='step', color='b', lw=2, density=True)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='b')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.hist(b, histtype='step', color='r', lw=2, density=True)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='r')
```

This gives the following output (which, I think, looks worse than what you obtained; I also changed cumulative=True to density=True in the first plot to be in line with the plot you provided):

[image]

Also, strictly speaking this does not make sure that the maxima are *really* identical. If you want to do that you can force it by doing e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
n1, _, _ = ax1.hist(a, histtype='step', color='b', lw=2, density=True)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='b')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
n2, _, _ = ax2.hist(b, histtype='step', color='r', lw=2, density=True)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='r')
ax1.set_ylim([0, n1.max()*1.1])
ax2.set_ylim([0, n2.max()*1.1])
```

Comment: Thanks, that is great !

Answer (score 1):

The following code would give `a` the same max as `b`:

```
a *= b.max()/a.max()
```

The cumulative flag in a might break this though and it should be placed before the histograms are generated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but that is not exactely what I need.

What I want is thust to have the same max for all distibutions, but without changing the standard deviation